# AsyncImage not working with google drive image URL

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to display an image from a google drive url using AsyncImage. The URL has public access(Anyone with the link can view it)

```
  ...
    ZStack {
            AsyncImage(url: trip.photoUrl) { phase in
                if let image = phase.image {
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                } else if let error = phase.error {
                    Color.red
                        .onAppear {
                            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                } else {
                    Image(cardbg)
                }
            }
   }
  ...
```

I keep getting the error: this operation couldn't be completed. But Opening the image url on any browser works fine. Also AsyncImage loads image urls from cloudinary work just fine. How do I resolve this error? Is it a permissions problem?

Comment: Does the link really resolve to the image itself, or is it a page that _hosts_ the image (eg a HTML page with the image imbedded in it). I'm guessing the latter

Comment: print `error`, not `error.localizedDescription`

Comment: Just checked using devtools in the browser. the link resolves to the image itself.

Comment: Are you logged in? Do you need to be logged in to get the image?

Comment: since `Anyone with the link can view it` can you post the link, so we can test your code.

Comment: Just checked very closely. It does resolve to a page. Thanks all for the clarification

Comment: You won’t be able to use Google Drive for a purpose like this

Comment: Everyone can access it: ok. But what's the output in the end of the URL? Is it an image embedded in some HTML (PhP, JS, etc.) or is it directly the image? That would change everything and explain why it fails. So do a `cURL` on your link, or use a `URLSession` code to get exactly what's at the end of the URL.

Comment: For instance, if I have access to a GDrive document image with a link, if I do a cURL on it, I get `<!DOCTYPE html><style nonce=..."`, which clearly shows that I don't get directly an image, but a webpage, that will show an image. Is that your case?

Comment: The OP already clarified above that it resolves to a page, not an image.

Comment: @jnpdx Missed that comment, I don't know how. >_<